# OSGi Virgo integrated with Arquillian

Tags: jboss-arquillian, eclipse-virgo

I would like to know if is possible to integrate virgo with arquillian for testing web app
Is ?

Thanks,

Junior

Answer (score 0):

from the list of [modules](http://arquillian.org/modules/) there is currently no explicit Arquillian support for Virgo out of the box available.

But there are some options you could try with [arquillian-container-osgi](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-osgi):

If you are using Virgo Nano you should be fine with the Equinox module.
Otherwise you could give the Remote Container Setup a try and use OSGi Enterprise JMX.

Hope this helps,
  florian